# Learning materials about Time Series Forecasting?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, references

I am a beginner in Time Series Forecasting meaning I have created some simple forecasting models and used them and I am also familiar with Stats and Probability but not that good just some basic concepts. I don't know the fundamentals of how they work and the maths behind them and their concepts. I am not that good at maths but I can learn if I will get a roadmap or some advice.

Note: I only know python not R. So, please only recommend courses, books, and articles which use python.

Thanks

Comment: How deeply do you want to go into the mathematics? Are you fine with using software that fits your models without knowing exactly how this is done, or do you need to understand precisely how parameters are estimated?

Comment: Hi @StephanKolassa I want to understand precisely their in and out and how they are working there everything.

Comment: OK, that helps. I'll still keep this one closed as a duplicate, but will try to draw more attention to the fact that we don't have a lot that really goes deeper. I'll add a book on Exponential Smoothing to the duplicate.

Comment: Thanks, @StephanKolassa I got some answers from the above link. I will first explore them.